# Angularjs bind HTML tags inside a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

Consider the following code which is in my controller file,

```
$scope.update = "<div class='search'><input type="search" name="search" /></div>";
```

I want to bind this `$scope.update` in view inside another `div` tag. Is it possible to do it in `angular.js`?

Comment: You mean something like the `ng-bind-html` directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: What do you need this for? It's likely that there's a better way to do it than inserting HTML.

Comment: I have a textbox which autocomplete the place that we search for, I have get the place and calculated the map relative tasks and generated a map in controller with html tags, which needs to be updated when the user changes his place/city and select in the textbox.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to build custom directives with AngularJS. Maybe this article can help you: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Comment: Please see the plunker link for better understand my problem - http://plnkr.co/edit/CBXThWRHdnHwa5RZXD0C?p=info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to use angular-sanatize library.

Add angular-sanatize.js in your html and in your module give a dependency of "ngSanitize"

And let us say rather than

```
<div>{{update}}</div>
```

use

```
<div ng-bind-html="update"></div>
```

For more details, please refer to "https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize"

Comment: I have tried this, I'm getting the following result. <div class="ng-binding">"<div class='search'><input type="search" name="search" /></div>"</div>. Inside the div tag, div tag is binded with the double qoutes, which result in display the div tags in the browser and not rendering the div tags.

Comment: You need to change your HTML to use single quotes for the attributes if you're going with this approach, like this: `$scope.update = "<div class='search'><input type='search' name='search' /></div>";`

Comment: Please see the plunker link for better understand my problem - http://plnkr.co/edit/CBXThWRHdnHwa5RZXD0C?p=info

Comment: What was missing - 1) 'ngSanatize' dependency while creating your module. 2) In html {{update}} was supposed to be updated with <div ng-bind-html="update"></div> 3) Now because you had style in your html, we have to use $sce service to retain, otherwise they would have been lost with ng-bind-html.

Comment: Additionally, I will suggest, if you only want to paint the text in the input box below it, you ng-model, with that you will not even have to write the function. And you can also, avoid this ng-bind-html by moving that div in html.